# How to use 2 jquery plugins in one html document?

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar

I want to use 2 different jquery plugins on the same page for a website. I have a table and I'm using [tinyscrollbar](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tinyscrollbar) to scroll when the table width is wider than the page layout. Now, I want to fix the header and the first column using [jQuery.FixedTable](http://www.novasoftware.com/Download/jQuery_FixedTable/JQuery_FixedTable.aspx)

I have basically zero experience with javascript and jqueries, but I'm guessing I need to somehow call both plugins in the ready event? I want both of these to work in the same html document - Can someone please let me know how this is done, and in what order it should be written?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure that you import the core jQuery script file, then the script files for your two functions. The order in which you call the plugin functions in your `ready` event handler (`$(document).ready(...);`) **may** not matter, unless the issue you're trying to fix with the second plugin is caused by the first.

Answer (score 0):

In sequence, you need to:

`<script` sections:

1. Reference the jQuery core and (if used) the jQuery UI libraries
2. Reference each of the two plug-ins

THEN, put in your code to USE the two plug-ins (such as the document ready call).

We could assist you more IF you provided your markup and the code you have tried including the references to each of the included libraries and plugins.